# using chapterbib with author-year citations

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I'm typesetting my PhD dissertation but have run in to some unexpected troubles using chapterbib. I'm working with a custom bibliography style file (`aea.bst`) and want LaTeX to typeset `\cite{boun01}` as (Bound, Brown and Mathiowetz, 2001) instead of [1]. However, when I compile my document, I receive the following error message

> 36: Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year
>   citations. (natbib)                Press  to continue in
>   numerical citation style.

A minimal reproducible example is provided below.

The main file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}
\include{chp01}
\include{chp02}
\end{document}
```

chp01.tex:

```
\blinddocument
\cite{boun01}
\cite{zeld89}
\bibliographystyle{aea}
\bibliography{sample}
```

chp02.tex

```
\blinddocument
\cite{boun01}
\bibliographystyle{aea}
\bibliography{sample}
```

sample.bib

```
@article{boun01,
title={Measurement error in survey data},
author={Bound, John and Brown, Charles and Mathiowetz, Nancy},
journal={Handbook of econometrics},
volume={5},
pages={3705--3843},
year={2001},
publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{zeld89,
title={Optimal consumption with stochastic income: Deviations from certainty equivalence},
author={Zeldes, Stephen P},
journal={The Quarterly Journal of Economics},
volume={104},
number={2},
pages={275--298},
year={1989},
publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
```

and finally, `aea.bst`, can be downloaded here http://faculty.ses.wsu.edu/Cassey/Webpage/Bib_files/aea.bst.txt

(save as `aea.bst`).

Thanks in advance, 
best, Sebastian

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your error. Your MWE works beautifully with TL2013 although `\cite{boun01}` produces the output (Bound et al., 2001) instead of (Bound, Brown and Mathiowetz, 2001).

Comment: I just compiled in TeXShop instead of Texpad, and everything works fine now. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error that could not be reproduced by others and seems to be resolved by the questioner.